# Prove that the expression is divisible by $(2^{2n}+1)^2$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a_n = 2^{2n}+1$ for a natural number $n$. Prove that $$(a_n-1)^{a_n}+1$$ is divisible by $a_n^2$.

We are to prove that $(2^{2n})^{2^{2n}+1}+1$ is divisible by $(2^{2n}+1)^2$. How do we do that?

Comment: What about induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward if you use binomial expansion.

Denote $b=a_n$.  Then 
$$(b-1)^b + 1 = \sum_{i=0}^b C(b, i) b^i (-1)^{b-i} + 1 = (-1)^b + C(b, 1)b (-1)^{b-1} + b^2(\sum_{i=2}^b C(b, i) b^i (-1)^{b-i}) + 1 = b^2 (-1)^{b-1} + b^2(\sum_{i=2}^b C(b, i) b^i (-1)^{b-i}) $$

is obviously a multiple of $b^2$. Note that we have used the fact that $b$ is odd and thus $(-1)^b + 1 = 0$.